# Kubernetes kube-dns pod is pending

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, kubeadm

I tried this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/) to install and setup Kubernetes in Ubuntu VM. I have finished upto 3/4 and now kube-dns pod is in pending status.
How can i figure out this?
here is the result for `kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system` and `kubectl describe pod <pod name>`

```
# kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
NAME                              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
dummy-2088944543-jk2t2            1/1       Running   0          3h
etcd-ubuntu                       1/1       Running   0          3h
kube-apiserver-ubuntu             1/1       Running   0          3h
kube-controller-manager-ubuntu    1/1       Running   0          3h
kube-discovery-1769846148-h88v4   1/1       Running   0          3h
kube-dns-2924299975-dfp17         0/4       Pending   0          3h
kube-proxy-zdcxw                  1/1       Running   0          3h
kube-scheduler-ubuntu             1/1       Running   0          3h
weave-net-xwfhj                   2/2       Running   0          2h

# kubectl describe pod kube-dns-2924299975-dfp17
Error from server (NotFound): pods "kube-dns-2924299975-dfp17" not found
```

Comment: Try using kubectl command to inspect the labels in the configuration data of the pod. Kubernetes well only schedule it only a host/kubelet which has matching labels. It could be that the pod for example has labels stating to only run in on a node which has a label "region=infrastructure" or something similar (that's just a made up example).also each kubelet has a notion of whether it is "schedulable" and it won't get anything automatically deployed onto it if this is not turned on. The last idea is that it possibly cannot download the container image. You can check the logs for that

Comment: @lakmal-vithanage can you post the output of `kubectl describe pod <pod-name>`?

Comment: @AntoineCotten, I have updated the question

Comment: @lakmal-vithanage you forgot `--namespace=kube-system` in the command, hence the error. Could you update the question one more time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Cause

Most likely a lack of available computing resources in your cluster.

If you're using the example in [cluster/addons/dns](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.10/cluster/addons/dns/kube-dns.yaml.base#L104-L108) you're certainly using a `Deployment` with resource requests, highlighted if you click the link. It could be that your other pods are already requesting all the available resources in the cluster, therefore your pod doesn't get scheduled.

You can confirm that theory with `kubectl --namespace=kube-system describe pod kube-dns-2924299975-dfp17` and look for the following event:

```
Reason                Message
------                -------
FailedScheduling      pod (kube-dns-2924299975-dfp17) failed to fit in any node
fit failure summary on nodes : Insufficient cpu (3)
```

You can also describe your nodes with `kubectl describe node <node-name>` and look at the last information:

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits      Memory Requests Memory Limits
  ------------  ----------      --------------- -------------
  320m (8%)     300m (7%)       150Mi (1%)      150Mi (1%)
```

In your case either the CPU or memory allocation should be close to 100%.

#### Solution

- Add more computing resources / nodes to your cluster (preferred)
- Remove the resource requests from your pod(s), at the risk of overcommitting your resources

Comment: this was also the issue in my case. Upgraded masters from `t2.micro` to `t2.small` and that fixed it.

Comment: @gsaslis Masters should not be schedulable in general, for security reasons. Upgrading them so that you can schedule pods on them is quite an anti-pattern.

Comment: yes, good point. In my case it was the `kube-scheduler` that couldn't be deployed... ; )

Comment: Is it possible to decrease/remove kube-dns default requests?